# Is there a way to extract class name from HTML using Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have been trying to scrape data from GlassDoor using Power BI and Power Query.

The problem comes into play when I want to record the data from the pop up as seen below.
[Glass Door Rating Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZwgW.png)

Normally Power Query would use the class as an identifier to record the data in a table but in this case each class name is different per number of stars. In this case a class of css-11w4osi would signify a 5-star rating while another class would signify 4-star ratings.
[Glass Door Rating HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ErP.png)

Using the class as an identifier does not produce usable results with the table just showing that a specific review has at least one 5-star component but not which one it is.
[Power Query Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCKge.png)
This code is what I got after using the edit your own table function in PowerBI after getting data from the web.

Is there a way to use the  as an identifier to get class names from Power Query?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you already created

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.